# How is an API key for odata.intel.com obtained?

Tags: api, hardware, intel, processors, opendata

I have just noticed Intel have an API to access their database of boards, chipsets and processors: http://odata.intel.com/

Anyone know how to register for an API key? I cannot find a sign-up form anywhere or other documentation. Anyone written an app using this data?

Comment: Interesting. this is related, though doesn't have an answer: http://communities.intel.com/thread/29372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this has changed since you asked the question. It's now quite trivial to request an API key -- simply go to http://odata.intel.com/ and click "Request API Key" from the right-hand sidebar. I received mine within seconds, though they claimed it'd be 1-3 days.

Comment: Where exactly did you find the key? Did they send it to your email?

Comment: Yes, it was in an email.